# Collecting metadata into table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have tabluar data that passes through a C# program that I need to collect some metadata on before finishing.  The metadata is always counts based on fields of the data.  Also, I need them all grouped by one field in the data.  Periodically, I need to add new counts to this collection of metadata.

I've been researching it for a little while, and I think what makes sense is to rework my program to store the data as a `DataTable`, then run LINQ queries on the table.  The problem I'm having is being able to put the different counts into one table-like structure and then write that out.

I might run a query like this:

```
var query01 = 
    from record in records.AsEnumerable()
    group record by record.Field<String>("Association Key") into associationsGroup
    select new { AssociationKey = associationsGroup.Key, Count = associationsGroup.Count<DataRow>() };
```

To get a count of all of the records grouped by the field Association Key.  I'm going to want another count, grouped in the same way:

```
var query02 =
    from record in records.AsEnumerable()
    where record.Field<String>("Number 9") == "yes"
    group record by record.Field<String>("Association Key") into associationsGroup
    select new { AssociationKey = associationsGroup.Key, Number9Count = associationsGroup.Count<DataRow>() };
```

And so on.

I thought about trying `Union` chain the queries but I was having trouble getting them to union since I'm projecting into anonymous types.  I couldn't figure out how to do it differently to make a union work better.

So, how can I collect my metadata into one table-like structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by creating a class that holds the set of records I need as a `DataTable`.  A user can add queries through a method, taking an argument `Func<DataRow, bool>`.  The method constructs the query supplying that argument as the where clause,  maintaining the same grouping and properties in the resulting anonymous-typed object.

When retrieving the results, the class iterates over each query stored and enters the results into a new `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to union because you have different types. Add Number9Count and Count to both annonymous types and try union again.